# Meteor Tutorial: see all properties of event

Tags: events, meteor, properties

I'm following the official tutorial on [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/try/4). We are attaching an event to a template (step 4).

HTML

```
<form class="new-task">
 <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
</form>
```

JS

```
Template.body.events({
  "submit .new-task": function (event) {
    var text = event.target.text.value;
```

I get the suggestion to add a console.log(event) to check out all properties of event. When I add the console.log(event) this in Chrome console, I can see the tree of a jQuery event with a lot of properties but I can't seem to fined the property that is stored in text variable.

I've also tried console.log(event.target) and console.log(event.target.text) but neither gives me a tree of properties and console.log(event.target.text.value) just logs the expected value to the console.

Which console.log(?) do I have to do to find the path to event.target.text.value ? Or is not possible to see this in Chrome console ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a transition from the jQuery API to the DOM API that one has to be aware of. The entered value isn't a property of the event, but belongs to a DOM element and is accessible via the DOM API.

In the tutorial, `event.target` is the form that we defined in the HTML. `event.target.text` accesses the `<input name="text">` element, which is a [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), outside of Meteor's purview.

[image]

From there on, you can use all the [HTMLInputElement properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), including `value`.

Try setting a breakpoint on the line that gets `event.target.text.value`, and type in the console `event.target.text` to see the available properties.